# Post elements that is not in the form tag?

Tags: php, javascript

I have code like so:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="blabla.php" class="addToCart">
  <input type="button" onclick="addToCartMulti();" value="Add Tracks to Cart" id="addToCart" name="addToCart">
</form>
```

Outside of the form tags, I have tracklisting:

```
<ul>
 <li><input type="checkbox" checked onclick="onSongClick(this);" id="trackNr_1" name="trackSelect" class="trackSelectionCheck"> 1. Train Love</li><li>
  .....
</ul>
```

I want to be able to post the form and include these other values. I have something like this for the JavaScript so far:

```
function addToCartMulti() {
  $("input.trackSelectionCheck").each(function(index) {
              var track = $(this).attr("id");
              var start = 8;
              var end = track.length;
              track = track.substring(start,end);
              $("form.addToCart").submit();
        });
  }
```

So the problem is that somewhere before this: `$("form.addToCart").submit();`. I need to add some JavaScript to actually include the other checkboxes so they are posted to the page.

Note: I don't want to use ajax.

Comment: Move the `input`s inside the `form` before submitting?

Comment: Is there a reason why the track listing needs to be outside the form? Maybe you can put hidden inputs in your form, and update their values when the check boxes are clicked.

Comment: In this scenario I can't move it in.

Comment: I'd prefer to grab it, because the track listing's position can change on the page. Also, I dont want to have one form tag at the top of the page, as there are multiple individual forms throughout pages.

Comment: It's possible to use JavaScript to create a hidden form field and copy the checkbox value into it on form submission, but it's far better to simply reorganize your HTML markup to include that field in the form in the first place.  OR... Create a hidden field on the form and bind the checkbox `onchange` to update that hidden form field

Comment: so my way isnt possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a hidden form field to your form, and then copy that track data you need, in whatever format you want (eg, a comma delimited list), into that hidden field.  Then call submit just as you are doing now.

Note: It appears you currently calling sumbit inside of the "each" loop, which is probably not what you want.  You want to process all the checkboxes with each, and then after that is done, do the submit.  So the "submit()" call should be outside of that each loop, unless I am misreading your intention.

Comment: This is the hard way of doing it. I'm looking for a way to submit an input box, as is, without moving it into the <form>. I'm guessing this is not pissible?

Comment: Yeah if the form element, whether it's a hidden field or input box, is not inside the form tags, you're going to have to use javascript to add it to what's being posted.  You're choices are pretty much (A) redo your html so you what you need is inside the <form> or (B) use javascript to add it to the form before it's submitted

Comment: I'm marking this as right, because of this last commment. That's what I wanted to know...